# jquery not finding id/table cell

Tags: jquery

I am trying to code a dynamic checkbox tree.
I do this using c:forEach statements and then using jquery to show/hide the relevant subsequent group of checkboxes.

Something strange is happening in that jquery only recognizes some of the table cells.

In the code below, only the first group of checkboxes ("upperMostExpertise") performs as it should as well as the first checkbox in the second category (the first "expertise2").

There is a request parameter which I set earlier but I think it should be clear what the code is trying to do.

The checkbox tree is not cosmetically perfect yet but I still would like to understand why it is not performing as it should (specifically, when I click on some of the checkboxes the subsequent td cell does not become visible while when I click on others it does).

I am not sure if the problem lies in the jquery code or in the dynamically generated html code.

The html code:

```
<table border="1">

<script>

</script>

            <tr>

                <td>

                    <c:forEach var="expertise" items="${upperMostExpertise.subExpertise}">

                        <input type="checkbox" name="${expertise.level}"
                           value="${expertise.name}" id="${expertise.name}">
                        ${expertise.name}<br>

                    </c:forEach>

                </td>

                <c:forEach var="expertise1"  items="${upperMostExpertise.subExpertise}">

                    <c:forEach var="expertise2" items="${expertise1.subExpertise}"
                               varStatus="count">

                        <c:if test="${count.first}">
                            <td id="${expertise1.name}" style="display: none">
                        </c:if>

                        <input type="checkbox" name="${expertise2.level}"
                               value="${expertise2.name}" id="${expertise2.name}">
                        ${expertise2.name}<br>

                        <c:if test="${count.last}">
                            </td>
                        </c:if>

                    </c:forEach>

                </c:forEach>

                <c:forEach var="expertise1" items="${upperMostExpertise.subExpertise}">

                    <c:forEach var="expertise2" items="${expertise1.subExpertise}">

                        <c:forEach var="expertise3" items="${expertise2.subExpertise}"
                                   varStatus="count">

                            <c:if test="${count.first}">
                                <td id="${expertise2.name}" style="display: none">
                            </c:if>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="${expertise3.level}"
                                   value="${expertise3.name}">${expertise3.name}<br>

                            <c:if test="${count.last}">
                                </td>
                            </c:if>

                        </c:forEach>

                    </c:forEach>

                </c:forEach>

            </tr>

        </table>
```

The jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
                    var inputName = $(this).attr("value");
                    $("td#" + inputName).toggle();
                    console.log("inputName variable equals " + inputName);
                    console.log("target td cell id is: " + $("td#" + inputName).attr("id"));
                    console.log("id of this table cell is: " + $(this).parents("td").first().attr("id"));
                    console.log("this table cell style attribute is: " + $(this).parents("td").first().attr("style"));
                });
            });
```

Comment: either use live('click'... or on('click',.....

Answer (score 1):

You need event delegation for the dynamically created checkboxes, use `.on()` like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function(){
        var inputName = $(this).attr("value");
        $("td#" + inputName).toggle();
        console.log("inputName variable equals " + inputName);
        console.log("target td cell id is: " + $("td#" + inputName).attr("id"));
        console.log("id of this table cell is: " + $(this).parents("td").first().attr("id"));
        console.log("this table cell style attribute is: " + $(this).parents("td").first().attr("style"));
    });
});
```